# RealmSwift Unit Test For Realm.io Migration

Tags: unit-testing, swift2, xcode7, realm, realm-migration

I need to write unit case for `realm.io` migration. How do i simulate a before and after `Object Class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to have a *realm file* previously saved (such as in your unit test bundle) with the schema version from which you want to test the migration. Your *realm object* in code is kept in its most recent version, while the realm schema in disk contains an older version.

Have a look at the [migration sample app](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift/Migration).

In the sample there are versions `V0`, `V1` and `V2` of the same `Person` object, as well as three different realm database files with different schema versions `default-v0.realm`, `default-v1.realm` and `default-v2.realm`.

The same `migrationBlock` is then used in all versions of the database to ensure it can correctly bring any possible old schema to the newest `V2`.

Comment: Thanks! How could i miss that!

Comment: But doesn't opening the realm file and running the migration change the file on disk automatically? How would you run the unit test a second time?

Comment: Make a copy of the database file and use that for running the tests.